# Rolling a token auth mechanisim on top of devise [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Aloha,

After discovering Devise' token_authenticatable has been depreciated, I'm now attempting to roll my own solution, however I think I'm having an issue with devise' sign_in method:

spec:

```
context "with an admin user" do
    before(:each) { @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, account_type: 'admin') }
    it "should respond with a 200 status" do
        post :verify, "token"=> @user.authentication_token
        response.status.should eq(200)
    end
 end
```

error:

```
1) UsersController#verify with an admin user should respond with a 200 status
     Failure/Error: post :verify, "token"=> @user.authentication_token
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:24:in `authenticate_user_from_token!'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # If there's a token present we're using the api authentication
  # mechanism, else we fall back to devise auth
  before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!, :authenticate_user!

  # Setup an AccessDenied error
  class AccessDenied < StandardError; end
  # setup a handler
  rescue_from AccessDenied, :with => :access_denied


  private

  # API requests should be made to the resource path
  # with the requesters token as params.
  #
  # This method extracts the params, checks if they are
  # valid and then signs the user in using devise' sign_in method 

  def authenticate_user_from_token!
    user = User.find_by_authentication_token params[:token]

    if !user.nil? && user.admin?
      # store: false ensures we'll need a token for every api request
      sign_in user, store: false # this is the line the spec complains about
    else
      raise ApplicationController::AccessDenied
    end
  end

  def access_denied
    render :file => "public/401", :status => :unauthorized
  end


end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  [snip]

  # We use this 'verify' method to provide an endpoint
  # for clients to poll for token verification
  # If the before filter rejects the user/token
  # they recieve a 401, else we respond with a 200
  # and the user params for verification on the remote app
  def verify
    user = User.find_by_authentication_token params[:token]
    render json: user
  end
end
```

I don't know where the 'user' method the error mentions is being called, nor what the object it's being called on is.

Comment: Having the same problem. Would love if anyone shared some insight!

Comment: I'm one of these awful people that just moves straight on when I find a problem, rather than coming back and adding an answer. I did get past this though as I ended up rolling this lot into a little gem. IIRC, this was a problem to do with the test env rather than the actual app. I'll go back through it and find out what I did..

Answer (score 0):

I've found Authy's [devise module](https://github.com/authy/authy-devise) very easy to use/modify for token based authentication, rather than rolling my own from scratch.

Comment: I think the OP means token authentication, not two factor authentication.

Comment: I see, I took token to mean a hardware token or authentication token such as a soft token or SecureID. Thanks for the correction.